# Nextflow: Use a variable defined in the `exec` block as process' output (Groovy)

Tags: groovy, nextflow

In my Nextflow pipeline, I have a process written in Groovy. So I want to execute the latter in an `exec` block (cf. [docs](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#native-execution)) and return one of its variables as the process' output.

Here's an example:

```
process my_process {
  output:
    val(myList), emit: my_process_output

  exec:
    def myList = []
    myList.append(1)
    myList.append(2)
    myList.append(3)
}

workflow {
  my_process()
  my_process.out.my_process_output.view()
}
```

However, this pipeline run on Tower returns the following error:

```
Downloading plugin nf-google@1.4.5
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.10.6
Pulling <repo> ...
downloaded from https://github.com/<repo>.git
Launching `https://github.com/<repo>` [<run_name>] DSL2 - revision: <commit SHA>
WARN: Process 'my_process' cannot be executed by 'google-lifesciences' executor -- Using 'local' executor instead
WARN: Local executor only supports default file system (unless Fusion is enabled) -- Check work directory: gs://<org>/scratch/<uid>
WARN: Tower request field `workflow.revision` exceeds expected size | offending value: `<git branch>`, size: 42 (max: 40)
Monitor the execution with Nextflow Tower using this URL: https://tower.<my_org>/orgs/<URL>
[01/31785c] Submitted process > my_process
[01/31785c] NOTE: Process `my_process` failed -- Error is ignored
WARN: Tower request field `workflow.revision` exceeds expected size | offending value: `ss-3597/compare-basespace-and-gcp-filesize`, size: 42 (max: 40)
Saving cache: .nextflow/cache/<sha> => gs://<org>
```

**Question:** How to return a variable defined/computed in the `exec` block as the `process`' output?

Answer (score 1):

The following syntax works:

```
process my_process {
  output:
    val(myList), emit: my_process_output

  exec:
    myList = []
    myList.add(1)
    myList.add(2)
    myList.add(3)
}

workflow {
  my_process()
  my_process.out.my_process_output.view()
}
```

In addition to the <strike>`append`</strike> → `add` typo, the key is to *not* use `def` when creating the `myList` variable.

Comment: Correct - `myList` just needs to be globally scoped to be used outside the `exec` block. This is not specific to the `exec` block though. You could replace `exec` with `script` in your example to reproduce both the problem _and_ the solution.